# SharePoint Online : Promoted State for Site page should be o but when i create site page using template it shows 2

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does any one know why when we create a site page using a template it shows the promoted state as 2 instead of 0.

I have made the promoted state column editable and from then this is the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Found that when i post a site page the promoted state shows as 2 (2 is a published news post not a site page) the reason is the site content of the template is a repost page but it should be a Site Page and it is the reason why the Promoted State shows as 2 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

The "**Promoted State**" value:

- **0** is a **published Site page** that is not considered News and does not end up in the News roll up web part (ie, your home page)
- **1** is a **News page** that is **not published** yet
- **2** is a **News page** that is **published** or a news link (from the News roll up  web part)

**Please check the following troubleshooting:**

1. Whether you are using page template is "**News page**" type?

[image]

2.When you publish a new page, if you select "**Post as News on this site**" option?

[image]

Comment: Hello @EchoDU_MSFT I said site page not the news post